# Fetch JSON data that has multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, fetch-api

I'm making a fetch to the API to grab the total number of players, the returned data is below:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 558,
        "first_name": "Dave",
        "height_feet": null,
        "height_inches": null,
        "last_name": "Jamerson",
        "position": "",
        "team": {
            "id": 11,
            "abbreviation": "HOU",
            "city": "Houston",
            "conference": "West",
            "division": "Southwest",
            "full_name": "Houston Rockets",
            "name": "Rockets"
        },
        "weight_pounds": null
    },
    {
        "id": 559,
        "first_name": "Scott",
        "height_feet": null,
        "height_inches": null,
        "last_name": "Brooks",
        "position": "",
        "team": {
            "id": 18,
            "abbreviation": "MIN",
            "city": "Minnesota",
            "conference": "West",
            "division": "Northwest",
            "full_name": "Minnesota Timberwolves",
            "name": "Timberwolves"
        },
        "weight_pounds": null
    },
    {
        "id": 560,
        "first_name": "Rolando",
        "height_feet": null,
        "height_inches": null,
        "last_name": "Blackman",
        "position": "",
        "team": {
            "id": 7,
            "abbreviation": "DAL",
            "city": "Dallas",
            "conference": "West",
            "division": "Southwest",
            "full_name": "Dallas Mavericks",
            "name": "Mavericks"
        },
        "weight_pounds": null
    },
    {
        "id": 561,
        "first_name": "Avery",
        "height_feet": null,
        "height_inches": null,
        "last_name": "Johnson",
        "position": "",
        "team": {
            "id": 8,
            "abbreviation": "DEN",
            "city": "Denver",
            "conference": "West",
            "division": "Northwest",
            "full_name": "Denver Nuggets",
            "name": "Nuggets"
        },
        "weight_pounds": null
    },
    {
        "id": 562,
        "first_name": "Rod",
        "height_feet": null,
        "height_inches": null,
        "last_name": "Higgins",
        "position": "",
        "team": {
            "id": 10,
            "abbreviation": "GSW",
            "city": "Golden State",
            "conference": "West",
            "division": "Pacific",
            "full_name": "Golden State Warriors",
            "name": "Warriors"
        },
        "weight_pounds": null
    },
    {
        "id": 566,
        "first_name": "Sam",
        "height_feet": null,
        "height_inches": null,
        "last_name": "Vincent",
        "position": "",
        "team": {
            "id": 22,
            "abbreviation": "ORL",
            "city": "Orlando",
            "conference": "East",
            "division": "Southeast",
            "full_name": "Orlando Magic",
            "name": "Magic"
        },
        "weight_pounds": null
    },
    {
        "id": 567,
        "first_name": "Isiah",
        "height_feet": null,
        "height_inches": null,
        "last_name": "Thomas",
        "position": "",
        "team": {
            "id": 9,
            "abbreviation": "DET",
            "city": "Detroit",
            "conference": "East",
            "division": "Central",
            "full_name": "Detroit Pistons",
            "name": "Pistons"
        },
        "weight_pounds": null
    }
],
"meta": {
    "total_pages": 39,
    "current_page": 1,
    "next_page": 2,
    "per_page": 100,
    "total_count": 3828
}
```

Problem is, the API only allows for a max of 100 results. As you can see in the "meta" object at the bottom, there is a total_count of 3828 and 39 pages, how would I access the other pages and get all 3828 results? currently I only get the first page with 100 results when I fetch.

```
const getPlayers = () => {
  fetch(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=100`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch(playerActions.getPlayers(data)));
}
```

Comment: https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=100&page=2

But, you cannot just query all pages...
Because, for example, on 1 query - BOB will be on  1 place, but on the last query he will be on 3 place.. So you cannot say what is true. So, you should ask it to API provider

Comment: Why do you set `per_page=100`? Do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: @jabaa I set it to 100 because that's the max amount per call, was trying to get as many as possible to fill the array.

Comment: @jabaa Here is the link to the documentation https://www.balldontlie.io/#players

Comment: You have to send one request, read the meta data and send more requests to get all data.